# Getting GPS locations and other attributes - BEGINNER

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am currently doing [this tutorial](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/) to get the GPS coordinates of my present location. I need to know what [these values](http://www.vellios.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/CoreLoc.png) means?

The first 2 values are the `geo-coordinates`, and i don't know what the other attributes are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126) what you are seeing as a result of the `description` selector being sent to your `CLLocation` object (which represents your current location and other location-related info):

> A string of the form `<<latitude>, <longitude>> +/- <accuracy>m (speed
>   <speed> kph / heading <heading>) @ <date-time>`, where `<latitude>`,
>   `<longitude>`, `<accuracy>`, `<speed>`, and `<heading>` are formatted floating
>   point numbers and `<date-time>` is a formatted date string that includes
>   date, time, and time zone information.

What you probably want to do now is extract info from your `CLLocation` object by accessing its various properties (e.g. `CLLocation.altitude` will return the altitude only). Generally, aside from debugging purposes to the console, you would not want to print or display to the user the result of `[CLLocation description]` which is what you have there!

Comment: So in that case can the speed ever be a `negative` value ?

Comment: I will refer once again to the document I linked to in the Developer Library (I suggest you give it a read!)


For the entry on `speed`, it says:

*This value reflects the instantaneous speed of the device in the direction of its current heading. A negative value indicates an invalid speed. Because the actual speed can change many times between the delivery of subsequent location events, you should use this property for informational purposes only.*

So no, the speed should not be negative (although the docs say that it could be, it would just be invalid).

Comment: Yes i read the document and i will read it once again. Since this is not the actual speed, is there any other way i could get the actual speed of the user travelling ?

Comment: Yes, you could work this out (well, a pretty good approximation) by using your `CLLocationManager` to get location updates, then calculate the speed using the old formula `speed = distance / time` where you can get the distance between two `CLLocation` objects with the `distanceFromlocation:` method and you can calculate the time simply by recording the time between the subsequent location updates.

This will require a little bit of work on your end!